# Android Composable Text breaks preview when it receives a Color parameter. Is there a workaround?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose

On any Android Studio version up to Bumblebee 2011.1.1 Canary 11, the following View does not render and in fact breaks the Previewer in unexpected ways.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun ColoredText(color: Color = Color.Red) = Text("text")
```

Stable version of Arctic Fox throws a MethodNotFoundError while the canary throws a warning saying it can't find the View. How can I get the preview to work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `@Preview Composables` the main restriction is that the ***Preview Composable functions must not take any parameters***.

Your `ColoredText` composable takes `color: Color = Color.Red` as a parameter hence doesn't render. You will also see the `@Preview Annotation` on your code highlighted in red.

To preview your code you can make a preview composable named `ColoredTextPreview()` which doesn't accept any parameter. Use this to preview the `ColoredText()` and pass in the Color Parameter

```
@Preview
@Composable
//preview doesn't accept parameters
fun ColoredTextPreview() = ColoredText(Color.Red)

@Composable
//create a 2nd non-preview composable that accepts parameters
fun ColoredText(color1: Color = Color.Red) {
    Text(
        text = "text",
        color = color1,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )
}
```

Be sure to include this line of code on your import statements to help with the Colors.

```
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
```

Thanks,

Comment: This is a good workaround, I'll just note that the IDE allows `@Preview` parameter does accept the function having parameters if they have default values so no red error highlighting occurs. And besides that there's also `@PreviewParameter` which merits mentioning but is out of scope for the question. Thanks nonetheless for the tip, I'll mark as answered.